# Image Rendering Issue In web browser

Tags: google-chrome, web

I have some issue on image rendering. I had same issue on several times while browsing **stacoverflow** and some other web sites.

This is the different

**Bad Rendering**

[image: Bad image Rendering]
[image]

**Good Image Rendering**

[image]
[image]

what is the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen in any browsers or just chrome? Do you use Vodafone?

If it's not just chrome, maybe your carrier compress images - vodafone does this, when you use their mobile connection.

Comment: This is now happen always.But now my stackoverflow.com it's like that,but no other website like that,but also already they have images.

Comment: Interesting. Are you on a notebook? Do you use windows with an antivirus software which could add some plugins to your browser?

Comment: Little test: http://borlabs.de/__tmp/ here you can see stackoverflows logo twice - does they look identical? Also, please look at the source code of my testpage - is it all in a single line or is it formated?

Comment: No i am using Google Chrome with Windows 7 and no any plugins installs into chrome.What's meaning of this part `sprites.png?v=f936a8b3d6ea`

Comment: this is what stackoverflow do. it's a sprite and because they often just update their sprite image, they add a version so they can force a browser to reload the image. does they look identical or is one image rendered incorrect (when yes, which one)?